# Apache loads x.wsgi file from django project, no __file__ attribute associated

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I am trying to load a python wsgi file called from apache with mod_wsgi.  My wsgi file attempts to reset the sys.path with:

```
import os, sys

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
sys.path.insert(0, root)
```

Apache complains with:
    `[Wed Feb 15 19:12:26 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]`

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings'
```

`(Is it on sys.path?): No module named`mysite.settings`

when I do:

```
>>> dir('mysite.wsgi')
```

It becomes apparent the `wsgi` file does not possess the `__file__` attribute, so my `sys.path` is not getting updated with the necessary directory.

Why would this `mysite.wsgi` file not have a `__file__` attribute?

Comment: That's not how `dir()` works...

Comment: It seems to work for me ... what is it I am missing?

Comment: I don't understand that, but it returns the same thing as before.  The problem is there is no __file__ attribute associated with that particular file object.

Comment: Have you stopped to think whether or not it's actually a file object?

Comment: You passed it a string. Three guesses as to whose attributes you're seeing, and the first two don't count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting path set to 'root', must be the parent directory of the directory where the Django settings.py is located and 'mysite' must be the name of that directory. You say nothing about the name of your project directory or where the WSGI file is located with respect to it, so not possible to tell you how your code is wrong.

Code under Apache will also run as special user, so project directory must be accessible/readable to that user.

Perhaps go watch:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

to better understand how to set it all up.

Answer (score 1):

It should work,
but you can also try and check if following code block helps.

```
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(DIRNAME)
```